# Extract the data from pg_dump for athena?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, database-backups

Can someone help me, please? I need to perform `pg_dump` from `DB` and that must be read by Athena

```
pg_dump  --> s3 < ---- aws athena
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL `pg_dump` format is pure SQL that can be run on a PostgreSQL database to create tables and load data. Open it in a text editor and take a look -- you'll see what I mean.

As a result, `pg_dump` files are **not in a format that can be used with Amazon Athena**.

Comment: Actually that is not strictly true. If the the `pg_dump` was done with `-Fc` it is in a compressed binary form and opening it with a text editor will show gibberish.  Please correct your answer to indicate that the plain text format is only one option.